# Why does `std::env::args` return an iterator of `String` instead of `&'static str`?

Tags: rust

What I remember from my operating systems class is that, at least in the OS we were working on, command-line arguments are stored somewhere in the process' address space. If that is the case, then couldn't `std::env::Args` be an iterator over `&'static str`? Or if the encoding of the strings is not necessarily UTF-8 and is operating-system dependent, couldn't `std::env::ArgsOs` be an iterator over `&'static OsStr`?

Comment: `fn main() { let name = String::new(); }` — `name` is also "stored in the process' address space". Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: Because it is a process-wide thing, it can be modified while we are iterating over it, see this great [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/13enrkv/why_does_stdenvargs_allocate/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

> [...] at least in the OS we were working on [...]

That's your answer.  Just because one OS stores command-line arguments literally in memory, doesn't mean they *all* do.  More than that, what's to say they store them in the exact same format that `str` expects?

The trivial example of this is Windows, where the command-line is a single potentially invalid UTF-16 string returned from a function call: there is *no way* to turn this into a `&'static str`.

So, the API is designed to return an owned string on the basis that it has to be consistent across platforms, and it doesn't know what it might have to do to get the command-line arguments into a usable format.

Comment: So the standard C main function `int main(int argc, charg**argv)` doesn't work on Windows?

Comment: It does, but it works by the C runtime parsing the command-line before invoking `main`.  It's a compatibility shim, not how it works natively from the OS's perspective.

Comment: I was wondering this same question but instead have been poking around for the reason `std::env::args_os()` returns an iterator of `OsString` instead of `std::ffi::OsStr`.  Any thoughts on this?